# When the enter key is pressed on the keyboard display some text

Tags: objective-c, ios, list, textview

This is what I want the app to do.

Tap in a "Text View" not a "Text Field", then the keyboard is displayed and a bullet point ("\u2022") pops up. You type your sentence, and when you hit return it makes a new bullet.

So essentially, you have a Text View that is a bulleted list.  Much like Word, where you start a bullet and when you hit return it make a new bullet for you, so you can start typing on that line.

[image: what I want my app to do]

How do I do this?

This is what worked for any other stupid noobs like me:

I put this into my .m file

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range  replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
{
NSString *modifiedString = [myTextView.text stringByAppendingString:@"\n\u2022"];
[myTextView setText:modifiedString];
return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

I put this into my .h file

```
@interface CRHViewController3 : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> {

    __weak IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView; 


}
```

and then I put this under my viewDidLoad

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

[myTextView setDelegate:self];   

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to look at making an NSNotification and I couldnt find a way to check when the return key was pressed.  Then I looked at this method, and because Im a newbie to Objective C I gave up on it    -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text.  And really I am just looking for someone who has a good approach to this problem.

Comment: You should handle that in `(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text` its quite easy with this delegate. Whenever you type the return key, the replacementText will be "\n", in this case you manually midify the text as u need , and return NO from this delegate method. Otherwise it will again modify your text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this.

```
(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if([text isEqualToString:"\n"])
    {
        NSString *modifiedString = [textView.text stringByAppendingString:@"\n\u2022"];
        [textView setText:modifiedString];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: So, I put this into my .m and changed textView to what my text view is called which is myTextView and it didn't work. Is there something else I have to do? Here is my Code:

Comment: -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
{
    NSString *modifiedString = [myTextView.text stringByAppendingString:@"\n\u2022"];
    [myTextView setText:modifiedString];
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}

Comment: I did an NSLog that was triggered when I get into this boolean, when i ran the app it never logged. Is there something i need to change in the BOOL.  is textView supposed to be myTextView or what?

Comment: Did you set the delegate of the textview to self while allocating it?

Comment: If you set the delegate, then only these delegate methods will get called. This method will be called onto the class which is set as the delegate

Comment: I did not set the delegate.  How and where would you do that?

Comment: how you have created the textView, if it via code do `[textView setDelegate:self]`, just after you do alloc init. If it is nib, ctrl + tap on your textView, in the popup drag from delegate to file's Owner.

Comment: What I have done is created a textView in my storyboard then I control click dragged from the textview into the header file... it wrote this code: @interface CRHViewController3 : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> {
    
    __weak IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView; 
    

}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14711/discussion-between-craig-and-sj)

Comment: Ok thats fine. Set the delegate in viewdidload of your controller . :-).

Answer (score 0):

The method `-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text` would be called for each letter entered on deleted.
So in this method you could try to replace all line breaks with bullet char.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
...
   textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\u2022"];
...
}
```

Comment: instead of replaceing "\\n", I think I would want to replace "\\n" with "\\n\u2022"?

Answer (score 0):

To use this code:

```
(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if([text isEqualToString:"\n"])
    {
        NSString *modifiedString = [textView.text stringByAppendingString:@"\n\u2022"];
        [textView setText:modifiedString];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Your header file must look like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> {

   //instance variables in here
}
```

Comment: do i have to change (BOOL)textview:(UITextView*)textview to fit the name of my textView at all?